# Post term block variations not generated for custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, block-editor

Since Gutenberg 13.3 (and WP 6.1), a post term block variation is generated for each custom taxonomy registered. For example, if you register a “Product category” taxonomy, you should able to add a “Product categories” block that lists all the product category terms assigned to the current post.

I'm working on a plugin that registers a couple of custom taxonomies for a custom post type:

```
function register_post_types() {

    // Register custom post type (omitted for brevity)
    (...)

    // Register custom taxonomies
    $cat_labels = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Exhibit Categories' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Category' ),
        'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'edit_item'     => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category' ),
        'search_items'  => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'     => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
    );
    $cat_args = array(
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'show_admin_column'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'labels'             => $cat_labels,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'exhibit_category', 'exhibit', $cat_args );

    $tag_labels = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Exhibit Tags' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Tag' ),
        'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'edit_item'     => __( 'Edit Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag' ),
        'search_items'  => __( 'Search Tags' ),
        'all_items'     => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
    );
    $tag_args = array(
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'show_admin_column'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'labels'             => $tag_labels,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'exhibit_tag', 'exhibit', $tag_args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
```

Both the custom post type and the custom taxonomy are registered correctly as they appear in the admin side menu, but for some reason when searching for the generated post term block variations using the block inserter they don't show up.

In the following screenshot you can see the issue (Both the "Product tags" and "Product categories" taxonomies come from a WooCommerce install):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the Gutenberg plugin? I'm not sure if these changes have been merged into WordPress core yet.

Comment: This feature was added in WP 6.1: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-6-1/#post-terms-block-variations-for-custom-taxonomy-terms

Comment: when does the registration code run? I can't see any functions wrapping it or hooks. I also can't get the same search results as your screenshot when testing, post tags don't show up at all,  "taxo" only gives me a term description block in the search

Comment: Here's the code that's meant to register the variations: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-terms/index.php#L79-L101

Comment: The code runs in the "init" hook. I updated the posted code.

Comment: The "post tags" block variations should appear in the "Theme" category in the inserter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for the post term block variation automatic generation to work you need to register the custom taxonomies earlier in the process (a priority lower than 10).

Example: `add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types', 9 );`

I don't know if this is by design because it's not documented anywhere in the Gutenberg docs.

Comment: Just stumbled on this gotcha with `register_taxonomy` too. If you don't set `priority` below 10, querying the custom taxonomy does not work.